# How to test the robustness of the cipher image against chosen and known plaintext attacks?

Tags: cryptanalysis

Is there any algorithm to test the robustness of the cipher image against chosen and known plaintext attacks?

Comment: I've never heard the term "cipher image", can you please give a short definition / explanation of what it means (with a comment or an [edit]), so you can get (better?) answers?

Comment: Encrypted Image

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to construct a system which is resilient to Chosen Plaintext Attacks and Known Plaintext Attacks, the method to do so is through provable security, not empirical tests. If you're attacking an existing scheme which has not been proven secure, typically you would perform a variant of one of the methods that have been used for cryptanalysis in the past. For instance, you can try [differential cryptanalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_cryptanalysis) or [linear cryptanalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_cryptanalysis).

Comment: There are limits to provable security: it proves the security of a construction (such as a cipher suitable to encipher large images) only hypothesizing the security of something else (such as the security of AES enciphering a 128-bit block). That later hypothesis might be simpler and widely accepted, but is not proved in a mathematical sense.